# RE: Can OpenCV, Python3 Modules Handle SPI Devices as Cameras?

Tags: python-3.x, camera, spi, opencv, python

I am working from these examples online: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html

I am using a pylepton library in Python also that is located here: https://github.com/groupgets/pylepton. Neither are related but...

- Does using OpenCV only stay dedicated to USB Cameras in general?
- And...
- Can OpenCV understand that I am using a '/dev/spidevX.X' device as a camera?

For instance, I have tried replacing '0' with a '/dev/spidev1.0' device like here...

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
```

like this:

```
cap = cv.VideoCapture('/dev/spidev1.0')
```

But...the error relayed via output states that cv.VideoCapture() is looking for an integer only.

I have tried some source exchanging like here:

```
with Lepton() as l:
    a,_ = l.capture()

    cap = (l.capture('/dev/spidev1.0') == cv.VideoCapture(0))
```

I know this is incorrect but I figured I would try it to counter some trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV is not designed to directly capture from SPI, therefore your code will not work easily.
Nevertheless, if you look into capturing a video, try capturing the images and with pylepton and then writing it to a videofile with openCV

```
import cv2
from pylepton import Lepton

running = True
out = cv2.VideoWriter('project.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'), 15, size)
with Lepton() as l:
  while running
    a,_ = l.capture()
    out.write(a)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"):
      break
out.release()
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you for your support. I will give you an arrow up when the source runs well on the machine in question.